# In Corda, how do I identify the timestamp of when specific change was made to a state object?

Tags: corda

Say I change the value of a state object property, for example change the owner from Alice to Bob at some stage during the state object lifetime. How do I efficiently get the timestamp for this change?

The only way I can think of is to retrieve the entire history of the state object based on linearId. Then compare each record with its previous one to see when the specific change took place and then look up the timestamp of the corresponding transaction. Is there a more efficient way?

Also is there any way to query transaction history to retrieve a transaction that included a specific attachment hash?

Answer (score 1):

currently you can't retrieve a transaction that included a specific attachment hash, you would need to do a linear search. Likewise with retrieving a timestamp. These are APIs that could be added.

It's actually quite easy to add this yourself. You can create a `CordaService` which uses the `jdbcSession` property of `ServiceHub` to query the transactions table based upon timestamps / attachment hashes.

Comment: Thanks Roger. Could I suggest a new feature for 'timestamping' changes to state objects. Currently I can see that timestamps can be retrieved by obtaining the related transaction hash from the state object (state.ref.txhash) and then looking up the hash in the statesMetadata to retrieve the recordedTime

Comment: I think it would be a nice feature to allow the transaction proposer to set a field in a transaction output state object to be equal to the transaction recordedTime (before you know what it is going to be). I think this would behave similarly to the ‘now’ keyword in EVM-Solidity which I believe allows you to set a value that equates to the block time, before you actually know what the block time is going to be.

Comment: Thanks Brian - I'll raise it with the product management team.